# ResponseExceptionMapper in cxf client

Tags: java, web-services, cxf, rest-client

I am trying to handle exceptions using the ResponseExceptionMapper  class for my cxf client.

**ExceptionHandlingCode:**

```
public class MyServiceRestExceptionMapper implements ResponseExceptionMapper<Exception> {


private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyServiceRestExceptionMapper .class);

public MyServiceRestExceptionMapper () {
}

@Override
public Exception fromResponse(Response response) {

    LOGGER.info("Executing MyServiceRestExceptionMapper class");

    Response.Status status = Response.Status.fromStatusCode(response.getStatus());

    LOGGER.info("Status: ", status.getStatusCode());

    switch (status) {

        case BAD_REQUEST:
            throw new InvalidServiceRequestException(response.getHeaderString("exception"));

        case UNAUTHORIZED:
            throw new AuthorizationException(response.getHeaderString("exception"));

        case FORBIDDEN:
            throw new  AuthorizationException(response.getHeaderString("exception"));

        case NOT_FOUND:
            throw new
                    EmptyResultDataAccessException(response.getHeaderString("exception"));

        default:
            throw new InvalidServiceRequestException(response.getHeaderString("exception"));

    }

}

}
```

CXF Client Code:

```
String url1= 
WebClient client = createWebClient(url1).path(/document);
client.headers(someHeaders);
Response response = client.post(byteArry);
```

For success scenarios, I am getting the correct response code of 200, but for failure scenarios, I never get a response code.

Also is there a better way of handling exceptions in cxf client.

Could someone please help on this.

Answer (score 1):

How have you registered the `ResponseExceptionMapper` to the WebClient?

You need something like this

```
List<Object> providers = new ArrayList<Object>();
providers.add(new MyServiceRestExceptionMapper() 
WebClient client = WebClient.create(url, providers);
```

I suggest to use a `WebApplicationException` insteadof `Exception` because default behaviour will raise this kind of exception if no `ResponseExceptionMapper` is registered. Also, return the exception, do not throw it. The  exception mapper should looks like this.

```
public class MyServiceRestExceptionMapper implements ResponseExceptionMapper<WebApplicationException>

    public MyServiceRestExceptionMapper () {
    }

    @Override
    public WebApplicationException fromResponse(Response response) {
         //Create your custom exception with status code
         WebApplicationException ex = ...

         return ex;
    }
}
```